# How can I make a mouth open in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I want to model an opening mouth. I don't know how and I don't find a good tutorial.[image]

Thanks

Comment: You may do it using shape keys (optionally driven by the bone controller) or using a single bone. Give me some time. I'lll try to show you how to do it ASAP.

Comment: You need a bone, because shapekey will have a linear interpolation but a bone will move the mesh in an arc. If you don't intend to animate you can just use the 3d cursor as a pivot point and soft selection to just rotate part of the geometry.

Comment: You can also mask out the sculpt and use big twist brush to open the mouth.

Comment: @Meri I just realized that you want to open his mouth in sculpt mode, right? My answer works only for retopologized meshes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## FOR RETOPOLOGIZED MESHES

### - USING SHAPE KEYS

Being in *Object Mode* create a new ***shape key*** and name it. Enter *Edit Mode* and press the *apply shapekeys in edit mode* button. Set the value of the key to *1*. Now enable the ***proportional editing*** and set it's type to ***Connected***. Select some vertices of the lower lip and press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd> to open the mouth.
[image]

If you want to apply the shape key value to the mesh you may use ***Create duplicate for editing*** option. It will create a duplicate of your model, but with the applied shape keys as a Basis key.
[image]

Optionally you may add a bone to control the shape key's value. Add a Single Bone (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>-->*Armature*-->*Single Bone*) and place it in front of mouth of your character. Select your model and add a ***Driver*** to your shape key (hover your cursor over shape key's value, press <kbd>RMB</kbd> and choose ***Add Driver*** option).
[image]

Now go to the ***Graph Editor***, change its mode to ***Drivers*** and select the shape key's name in the panel on the left. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the *properties shelf* and in *Drivers* panel change the *Type* to ***Average Value***. In *Variable* window choose ***Transform Channel***. Now set up things as pictured below- in this case we want the *Bone* (which belongs to *Armature*) to control the shape key's value only if it'll be transformed using *Local* *Yaxis*
[image]

You may now select the bone, then go to *Pose Mode* and control the shape key's value changing the bone's position.
[image]

### - USING BONES

Being in *Object Mode* add a ***Single Bone*** and place its base, where your model's jaw hinge is located. Select your model, then a bone and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->*Parent*-->*With Automatic Weights*.
[image]

Now go to *Edit Mode*, select the whole mesh <kbd>A</kbd> and press *Remove* button to set all weights to 0.
[image]

Now select the parts of a mesh you want to follow the bone's movement, change the *Weight* value to 1 and press *Assign*.
[image]

You may now assign specific weights values to desired vertices to make the deformations smooth. Enable ***Show Weights*** option in *Mesh Display* panel to see the weights in *Edit Mode*. Now assign desired weights to specific vertices. Remember that the higher the weight is, the more the painted area of the mesh will stick to/follow the bone.
[image]

You may also do it in a ***Weight Paint*** mode.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am trying to do the same option but I can't write anything in the ShapeKey.

Comment: I'm trying with brushes. Yes I can open the mouth but I can't do the smile. any suggestion?

Comment: I apologies I have found the brush to make a smile. Thanks again. But I don't know why I can't write any shapekey. Should I do something before that?

Comment: To rename the shape key hover your cursor over the key's name and press the LMB twice.

Answer (score 5):

## BEING IN SCULPT MODE

Select the ***Mask*** brush, set its type to *Add* and paint the upper lip area to mask it.
[image]

Now choose the ***Grab*** brush and use it to open the mouth.
[image]

Comment: A bit of the bridge of the nose appears to be moving as well.  Looks like the masked area needs to be larger, or the proportional editing needs to be smaller?

Comment: Good point friend! Masked area needs to be larger indeed.