How to deform mesh to have one side look like fire?
I'm looking to make a cartoon character, and I want the character to have eyes that look like they turn into fire. I'm looking to make one side of each eye to be normal, the other side to look like it's turned into fire, and blend between both sides. Any existing techniques or tools that can make this easy?

I'm no expert while using Blender, haven't really made much with it, but I have been editing existing projects for over a year now, so I'm no novice.

Not exactly fire looking, but an emission animation https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/244710/19307 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/194013#194013

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos That's interesting, though I was looking for a way to make the mesh deform into fire. Not just to have fire on the mesh. So, I want the eye to transition from normal shaped to fire shaped as it gets closer to the fire side of the eye.

Morph it with shapekeys https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45142/how-can-i-make-a-mouth-open-in-blender/45147#45147

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks, I'll try using these and see where it leads me.
